# Fibonacci numbers java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, arrays, list, fibonacci

I try to add Fibonacci numbers to a `List` and get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I need these numbers in a `List` or `array`, to manipulate it further.

Here is my code:

```
int a;
int b = 0;
int c = 1;

int prod = 2932589879121
    

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < prod; i++) {
    a = b;
    b = c;
    c = a + b;
    list.add(c);
}
```

How can I fix it?

My full code:

```
public static long[] productFib(long prod) {
    long[] result = new long[3];

    int a;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 1;

    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < prod; i++) {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;
        list.add(c);
    }

    int index = 0;
    while (true) {
        first = list.get(index);
        second = list.get(index + 1);
        if (first * second == prod) {
            result[0] = list.get(index);
            result[1] = list.get(index + 1);
            result[2] = 1;
            break;
        } else if (first * second > prod) {
            result[0] = list.get(index);
            result[1] = list.get(index + 1);
            result[2] = 0;
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I need to find if multiplication of two Fibonacci numbers from list give another Fibonacci number. This works fine for small numbers.

Changing the code to:

```
public static long[] productFib(long prod) {
    long[] result = new long[3];

    long a;
    long b = 0;
    long c = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < prod; i++) {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;
        if (a * b == prod) {
            result[0] = a;
            result[1] = b;
            result[2] = 1;
            break;
        } else if (a * b > prod) {
            result[0] = a;
            result[1] = b;
            result[2] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Works fine

Comment: Reduce the number you store or don't store but print? *Here is my code:* - no it isn't - it wouldn't compile

Comment: 2,932,589,879,121 is larger than the maximum value an int can hold (so this should already error out during compilation). An integer can only hold numbers up to 2 billion (you have almost 3 _trillion_). `c` will  be way larger than the maximum allowed value too and overflow. Every single int will require 4 bytes of memory. This means you need at least 11,730,359,516,484 bytes to hold all values in your list. That 11.7 Terrabytes. Do you have that much RAM in your computer? How did you come up with that upper limit in the first place?

Comment: the `ArrayList` uses an array to store the elements, and an array can never hold more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements since the size given in the Creation Statement must be promoted to an `int` (or just because the array cannot hold more elements) || @knittl and that was a very optimistic calculation: the List can one store references, so we need that many wrapper classes (additionally to the `int`), and I doubt the Fibonacci Numbers will be small enough to be stored as `int`, probably not even as `long`

Comment: maybe it would be better to use the [Closed-form Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)  to calculate such large numbers of the Fibonacci Squence

Comment: @user16320675 yes, that's why I wrote "at least" :)

Comment: Try: `long a,b,c;` ..?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  I need to understand the problem before I look at the code.  Can you provide examples?

Answer (score 0):

The value of prod is out of range. In java int (signed) has the range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. This should throw a compilation error "integer number too large".

Answer (score 0):

Work fine:

```
public static long[] productFib(long prod) {
    long[] result = new long[3];

    long a;
    long b = 0;
    long c = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < prod; i++) {
        a = b;
        b = c;
        c = a + b;
        if (a * b == prod) {
            result[0] = a;
            result[1] = b;
            result[2] = 1;
            break;
        } else if (a * b > prod) {
            result[0] = a;
            result[1] = b;
            result[2] = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `int` data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. Its value-range lies between -2,147,483,648 (-2<sup>31</sup>) to 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup>-1) (inclusive). Its minimum value is -2,147,483,648 and maximum value is 2,147,483,647.
Change the datatype of prod-int prod to long prod.
Because the `long` data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed long has a minimum value of -2<sup>63</sup> and a maximum value of 2<sup>63</sup>-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the `long` data type to represent an unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 2<sup>64</sup>-1.